# Partial restore with Back In Time

Tags: backup, restore, backintime

I'm trying different backup methods for my Linux machine. Came across Back In Time, and I like it, but:

Is there a way to restore just some of the backed up files/dirs?
Say I have selected dirs `*/A/`, `*/B/` and `*/C/`. The default restore option would restore all of them, but what if I only wnat to restore `*/A/`?

I can just dive into the backup directory (as the files/dirs are readily accessible), but that would only work for files, not directories. And besides that, it's just a workaround, doesn't feel the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the backintime UI, you can select a snapshot on the left, then navigate to the folder you want to restore on the right. Then you can right click on files and folders in the snapshot, and select "Restore" or "Restore to..." from the menu.

The former restores the file/folder to its original location, the latter allows you to choose where to restore it.